# Cannot add data to MongoDB Atlas "not authorized to execute command { insert: ... }"

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I **can** connect to MongoDB with the StringURI, **BUT** if I try to add a schema I get the **error message**:

```
MongoDB Connected ..
{ MongoError: not authorized on admin to execute command { insert: "animals", documents: [[{isEndangered true} {dateOfEntry 2019-10-03 22:33:54.852 +0000 UTC} {_id ObjectIdHex("5d967752e762ed56dc4f1dba")} {name Red Panda} {__v 0}]], ordered: true, writeConcern: { w: "majority" }, lsid: { id: {4 [194 242 186 89 84 47 69 212 143 253 85 42 86 82 70 95]} }, txnNumber: 1.000000, $clusterTime: { clusterTime: 6743708686104920070, signature: { hash: [247 92 77 50 
194 115 41 36 114 64 156 130 20 135 223 112 71 207 137 248], keyId: 6728180188896559104.000000 } }, $db: "admin" }
    at Connection.<anonymous> (C:\Users\xxxx\Documents\04_Programmering\mongoDB_Node\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\connection\pool.js:466:61)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:197:13)
    at processMessage (C:\Users\xxxx\Documents\04_Programmering\mongoDB_Node\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\connection\connection.js:364:10)
    at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\xxxx\Documents\04_Programmering\mongoDB_Node\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\connection\connection.js:533:15)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:197:13)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:288:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:269:11)
    at TLSSocket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:224:10)
    at TLSWrap.onStreamRead [as onread] (internal/stream_base_commons.js:150:17)
  ok: 0,
  errmsg:
   'not authorized on admin to execute command { insert: "animals", documents: [[{isEndangered true} {dateOfEntry 2019-10-03 22:33:54.852 +0000 UTC} {_id ObjectIdHex("5d967752e762ed56dc4f1dba")} {name Red Panda} {__v 0}]], ordered: true, writeConcern: { w: "majority" }, lsid: { id: {4 [194 242 186 89 84 47 69 212 143 253 85 42 86 82 70 95]} }, txnNumber: 1.000000, $clusterTime: { clusterTime: 6743708686104920070, signature: { hash: [247 92 77 50 194 115 41 36 114 64 156 130 20 135 223 112 71 207 137 248], keyId: 6728180188896559104.000000 } }, $db: "admin" }',
  code: 8000,
  codeName: 'AtlasError',
  name: 'MongoError',
  [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {} }
```

**My connection string:** (using the package 'config' without problems [tried without])

```
{
    "mongoURI": "mongodb+srv://xxxx:xxxx@xxxx-xxxx.mongodb.net/admin?retryWrites=true&w=majority"
}
```

**With Mongoose driver and connection:**

```
mongoose
    .connect(db, { useNewUrlParser: true, useCreateIndex: true, useFindAndModify: false, useUnifiedTopology: true})
    .then(() => console.log('MongoDB Connected ..'))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

**I have tried:**

- Whitelisted my current IP and 0.0.0.0/0 in the Network Access
- Authorized with two roles (both as AtlasAdmin and ReadWrite-user with correct usernames and passwords)
- With Connection String: mongodb+srv://:@xxxx-xxxxx.mongodb.net/admin?retryWrites=true&w=majority
- I'm aware of the limitation of Atlas but I'm trying to simply add the the table like this:

```
const newAnimal = new Animal({
    name: 'Red Panda',
    isEndangered: true
});

newAnimal
    .save()
    .then(item => console.log(item))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

New at this, and I don't want to quit before even starting.. A free Atlas account seems like a good start for smaller demos and learning, not having to deal with more than connection and Schemas etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is saying:

```
MongoError: not authorized on admin to execute command { insert: ....
```

This means that you are trying to insert into the `admin` database, which is a restricted special database.

Change your connection string to use another database, e.g.:

```
"mongodb+srv://xxxx:xxxx@xxxx-xxxx.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority"
```

so that you connect to the database called `test`. Your inserts should work.

Comment: I have changed my connString as indicated to `mongodb+srv://xxxx:xxxx@xxxx-xxxx.mongodb.net/playground?retryWrites=true&w=majority`, but am still getting the error preventing me from doing an insert.  The user belongs to the `readWriteAnyDatabase` role.  Any ideas as to what I am missing?

Comment: I've tried with a .find() instead of a .save(), and then I get `MongoError: user is not allowed to do action [find] on [admin.zips]`.  It's as if it's not making the switch to the `playground` database?!  My connectionString definitely has `...mongodb.net/playground?...` to indicate that I want to use the `playground` database.

Comment: uhg wow nevermind...it turns out the problem was in the version of `mongoose`.  I updated it and now it is working fine!

Answer (score 0):

As Shawn de Wet suggested in the comments, updating mongoose worked for me (from 5.0.2 to 5.13.15).